# How to create multiple edges from node a to b using cgraph library api?

Tags: c++, graphviz

I'm tring to create 2 edges from node a to b using Graphviz's cgraph library api, but the second call to agedge always returns NULL. Do I do sth wrong in the code below? Graphviz version is 2.34. Thanks.

```
#include "gvc.h"
#include "cgraph.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    GVC_t *context = gvContext();
    Agraph_t *graph = agopen((char *)("graph"), Agdirected, NULL);
    agsafeset(graph, (char *)("rankdir"), (char *)("LR"), (char *)(""));

    Agnode_t *a = agnode(graph, (char *)("a"), 1);
    Agnode_t *b = agnode(graph, (char *)("b"), 1);
    Agedge_t *e_ab0 = agedge(graph, a, b, (char *)("e_ab0"), 1);
    Agedge_t *e_ab1 = agedge(graph, a, b, (char *)("e_ab1"), 1);

    //e_ab1 is always 0
    cout << e_ab0 << endl << e_ab1 << endl;

    //other code...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agdesc_t dir = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };

Comment: It works on Linux, but not on Windows. [erg](http://www.graphviz.org/users/erg) told me to replace Agdirected with a local variable dir as a workaround.